# porque me aparece 0 al transformar un array de string a entero

Tags: array, ruby

[image: como hago para que al transformar de string a entero no me aparezca un 0 en el caso de string que dice '231as' y el 'b123'.n el resto si funciono la transformación pero en esos dos casos puntuales no]

como hago para que al transformar de  string a entero no me aparezca un 0 en el caso de string que dice '231as' y  el 'b123'.En el resto si funciono la transformación pero en esos dos casos puntuales no

Comment: Por favor, para la próxima copia y pega el código o cualquier cosa que sea un texto, es mucho más útil que un pantallazo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No explicas cuál es el resultado final que esperas para los casos que mencionas, pero supongo que quieres borrar cualquier carácter no numérico. Eso lo podrías lograr con una expresión regular y [`gsub`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub):

```
[1] pry(main)> pasosreloj = 'b123'
=> "b123"
[2] pry(main)> pasosreloj.gsub(/\D/, '').to_i
=> 123
```